# ChartJS - Labels getting cutoff using datalabels plugin

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a simple bar chart and I'm using the datalabels plugin to place labels inside each bar and at the top.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['One', "Two"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [40, .5],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 99, 132)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
      enabled: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 40
        },
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        maxBarThickness: 50
      }]
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: true,
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'top',
        color: 'white',
        offset: -30,
        font: {
          weight: 'bold',
          size: 14
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

But sometimes, I'll have a value that doesn't allow enough room for the label. See second bar on  https://jsfiddle.net/myckxLun/1/.

I want to make sure I have X amount of room for these labels. I've tried `minBarLength` for the Y-axis - but all this does is force the bar length to be a min pixel value and doesn't adjust the graph (i.e. the bar length is inaccurate).

Ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Using laber upper of bar is better than inside it. For your situation there is no solution. And datas could be 100 maybe other 1 . So u should use labels upper of bars

Comment: were you able to get a solution for this? @Harry